# Getting real color of a ViewGroup and compare with resource color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

I am trying to get color of a ViewGroup and trying to compare with a resource color.

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
```

In my code i am doing this.

```
ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) mainLayout.getBackground();
        if (viewColor != null)
        {
            int colorId = viewColor.getColor(); // i get -6371612
            int mainColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary); // i get -65536
            if (colorId == mainColor)
            {
                mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
```

The colorId and mainColor are not same. What am i missing? shouldn't they be same?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your code and it works flawlessly (the colors get compared and are equal).

BUT: when I set the background color of the `RelativeLayout` to `Color.RED` I also get the -65536 the you received.

So to put it another way: your code works fine, but the function gets called twice, the first time it sets the color of the layout to red (as the code instructs it to) and then when you try to check the colors don't match up (since one is red and the other is colorPrimary.

Comment: In which case, OP must have also got the values the wrong way around in the question.

Comment: no, the values are fine .. @+id/mainLayout gets just switched from colorPrimary to RED on the first (succesful) pass

Comment: He gets `mainColor` from a constant value, so it cannot change. I think its just a typo and that you are correct.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant .. you are right that it probably is just a typo